# Adding Tool Window to VSPackage Extension - not in View -> Other Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vspackage

According to this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn951126.aspx):

the Tool Window should just show up in the experimental instance's View -> Other Windows menu in VS2015, but mine doesn't.

However, when I try to add the Tool Window to the project (as in Add - New Item -> Custom Tool Window), I get a pop-up saying (when pressing 'OK'):

> Field not found: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory.CarriageReturnLineFeed'

It does seem to add the Tool Window to the project, but the 'Add New Item' dialog remains active and then I have to cancel it the second time.

I see a lot of older articles using different approaches as [this MZ-Tools article](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2015/MZ2015004.aspx) for example.

Should I rather use the MZ-Tools link's approach?
Is the MSDN article just wrong?
Is there something wrong with my VS setup (perhaps indicative by the pop-up)?

Comment: There is something wrong in your VS setup. You can use my article, but it is better that you fix your setup.

Comment: Thanks, my harddrive crashed on the 10th, so now I'm forced to re-install VS2015. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referencing one of the CodeAnalysis Release Candidate versions from NuGet. If so, update to the latest version (1.0.0).